# Contradictory Idioms

Tags: idioms, contractions, idiom-requests

I stumbled across some contradictory idioms, and it made me wonder how many idioms can be contradicted with other idioms! Some that I've collected so far:

> The pen is mightier than the sword
>
> Actions speak louder than words

---

> What you see is what you get
>
> Don't judge a book by its cover

---

> A stitch in time saves nine
>
> Good things come to those who wait

---

> Many hands make light work
>
> Too many cooks spoil the broth

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Unfortunately this question isn't really constructive, so I'm going to close it. If you can edit to ask for one pair, perhaps, for a specific situation then it can be reopened.

Comment: Let's cut to the chase. Name *one* idiom for which you think there is *no* opposite.

Comment: @RegDwighт, I think *idioms* generally don't have opposites; if you refer to sayings, proverbs, aphorisms, etc. then try "Takes one to know one" and "Don't beat a dead horse".  Among proverbs listed in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proverbial_phrases) many are so specialized that it is difficult to define an opposite or for an opposite to make sense.  Note, a sort of opposite for "The squeaky wheel gets the grease" is “No flies enter a mouth that is shut”.

Comment: @jwpat7 obviously I used the term *idioms* because that's what OP used in his question. With that ouf of the way, on to your examples. "Takes one to know one" → "You don't need a weatherman to know which way the wind blows". "Don't beat a dead horse" → "Nothing ventured, nothing gained"; "The waters wear the stones". I am sure there are more and better ones (and anyway as you point out opposites are defined by context), but the point is, proverbs are nothing but generalizations, and as we know all generalizations are wrong, thus contradicting generalizations are the norm, not the exception.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I should have used `proverb` instead of `idiom`. Shame this wasn't allowed to run :(